# when I clicking on Back button of browser , it should go to the previous activity of the same page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using VS 2008,ASP.NET,C#.NET.

I have a report with drill down feature in grid in web application.

i am using a same webpage for different click options(account group,subgroup,head account) of the same report page.

Suppose I am in webpage accounts.aspx

Now I am opening this report rptDisplay.aspx.

When I click on the account group, grid is filled as group wise .

When clicking on subgroup , grid is filled as subgroup wise .

When clicking on Back button of Browser , then it redirects to accounts.aspx page.
This is the present scenario.

But my requirement is when I clicking on Back button of browser , it should go to the previous rptDisplay.aspx with group selection dat.

How can we implement this?

Thanks in advance
George N t

Comment: Can you please put your code to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke full page postback in button click (Account group or Sub group). Then if click back button in your browser in will redirect to previous page.